# Counterparty flow on C=GB,L=London,O=Controller had an internal error and has terminated at

Tags: transactions, corda

```
net.corda.core.flows.UnexpectedFlowEndException: Counterparty flow on C=GB,L=London,O=Controller had an internal error and has terminated
        at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.erroredEnd(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:446)
        at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.confirmReceiveType(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:429)
        at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.waitForMessage(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:396)
        at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.access$waitForMessage(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:41)
        at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.sendAndReceive(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:559)
        at net.corda.core.flows.NotaryFlow$SendTransactionWithRetry.sendPayloadAndReceiveDataRequest(NotaryFlow.kt:177)
        at net.corda.core.flows.DataVendingFlow.call(SendTransactionFlow.kt:48)
        at net.corda.core.flows.DataVendingFlow.call(SendTransactionFlow.kt:31)
        at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:243)
        at net.corda.core.flows.NotaryFlow$Client.call(NotaryFlow.kt:70)
        at net.corda.core.flows.NotaryFlow$Client.call(NotaryFlow.kt:36)
        at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:243)
        at net.corda.core.flows.FinalityFlow.notariseAndRecord(FinalityFlow.kt:73)
        at net.corda.core.flows.FinalityFlow.call(FinalityFlow.kt:56)
        at net.corda.core.flows.FinalityFlow.call(FinalityFlow.kt:28)
        at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:243)
        at com.demo.flows.TradeFlow.call(TradeFlow.kt:130)
        at com.demo.flows.TradeFlow.call(TradeFlow.kt:21)
        at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:243)
        at com.demo.flows.DealFlow$Initiator.call(DealFlow.kt:124)
        at com.demo.flows.DealFlow$Initiator.call(DealFlow.kt:24)
        at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:96)
        at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:41)
        at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092)
        at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788)
        at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100)
        at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:69)
Counterparty flow on C=GB,L=London,O=Controller had an internal error and has terminated kotlin.Unit
net.corda.core.flows.UnexpectedFlowEndException: Counterparty flow on C=GB,L=London,O=Controller had an internal error and has terminated
```

I am trying to create three outputs with two input states. Contract verification, party signature, Counterparty signature, notary contract verification done but notary's counterparty flow got error. I am unable find the reason why this error occurs.

Notary got the warning as:

> WARN: [kryo] Unable to load class com.demo.structures.State with
>   kryo's ClassLoader. Retrying with current.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the Kryo warning.

Each node will output logs in a `logs` folder. Check the controller's log to see why it failed.